# As soon as I add the constraints in the inner CollectionView in my Nested CollectionView, it's starts a never ending loop

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, snapkit

[image]

Controller One is the first Collection view controller, From here, at cell selection, it navigates me to the controller two.

In Controller two I have two Nested Collection View.

A horizontal Collection View inside Vertical Collection View Cell.

My Issue is that when I try to add Any UI elements in Horizontal Collection View Cell then I could not be able to navigate from the first controller itself.

After spending a lot of time debugging the code, I found that when I add any UI element constraint on horizontal Collection View cell then this thing happens.But I don't know the solution.

Below is the code of both the Controller and sorry if I am not clear about the problem.

**ControllerOne**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import CodableFirebase

class HomeViewController : BaseViewController{


lazy var categoryCollectionView = UICollectionView()
var navModel: [NavigationModel] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .init(displayP3Red: 72, green: 54, blue: 13, alpha: 0.1)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .black
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .yellow
    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.title = "Title"
}

override func SetupUI() {

    //Sessions/Menu Grid/List
    let verticalFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    verticalFlowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    self.categoryCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero , collectionViewLayout: verticalFlowLayout)
    self.categoryCollectionView.delegate = self
    self.categoryCollectionView.dataSource = self
    self.categoryCollectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.categoryCollectionView.register(HomeCategoryCell.self,forCellWithReuseIdentifier: AppConstants.CellIdentifier.CategoryCellId)
    self.categoryCollectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

}

override func SetViewConstraints() {

    self.view.addSubview(categoryCollectionView)
    categoryCollectionView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.width.equalToSuperview().inset(30)
        make.height.equalToSuperview()
        make.centerX.equalTo(self.view)
        make.top.equalTo(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
    }
}


}

extension HomeViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate, 
 UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return navModel.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell : HomeCategoryCell = categoryCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: AppConstants.CellIdentifier.CategoryCellId, for: indexPath) as! HomeCategoryCell


    cell.categoryLabel.text = navModel[indexPath.row].label
    cell.imageURL = navModel[indexPath.row].backgroundImageURL

    cell.contentView.sizeToFit()
    cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = [UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleHeight]
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width = (view.frame.size.width - 60)
    return CGSize(width: width, height: 120)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let controller = SelectedCategoryViewController()
    controller.pageModel = navModel[indexPath.row].pages!
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}




}
```

**Controller Two**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SelectedCategoryViewController: BaseViewController {


lazy var subCategoryCollectionView = UICollectionView()
var pageModel: [PagesModel] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .init(displayP3Red: 72, green: 54, blue: 13, alpha: 0.1)
}

override func SetupUI() {

    //Sessions/Menu Grid/List
    let verticalFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    verticalFlowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    self.subCategoryCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero , collectionViewLayout: verticalFlowLayout)
    self.subCategoryCollectionView.delegate = self
    self.subCategoryCollectionView.dataSource = self
    self.subCategoryCollectionView.backgroundColor = .init(displayP3Red: 72, green: 54, blue: 13, alpha: 0.1)
    self.subCategoryCollectionView.register(SelectedCategoryCell.self,forCellWithReuseIdentifier: AppConstants.CellIdentifier.SelectedCategoryCellId)
    self.subCategoryCollectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

}

override func SetViewConstraints() {

    self.view.addSubview(subCategoryCollectionView)
    subCategoryCollectionView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.width.equalToSuperview()
        make.height.equalToSuperview()
        make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
        make.top.equalTo(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
    }
}


}

extension SelectedCategoryViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return pageModel.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell : SelectedCategoryCell = subCategoryCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: AppConstants.CellIdentifier.SelectedCategoryCellId, for: indexPath) as! SelectedCategoryCell

    cell.subCategoryLabel.text = pageModel[indexPath.row].label



    cell.contentView.sizeToFit()
    cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = [UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleHeight]
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width = (view.frame.size.width)
    return CGSize(width: width, height: 220)
}


}
```

**SelectedCategoryCell**

```
 import Foundation
 import UIKit

 class SelectedCategoryCell: BaseUICollectionViewCell {

var subCategoryLabel = UILabel()
lazy var subCategorySessionCollectionView = UICollectionView()



override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()


}

override func SetupUI() {
    subCategoryLabel.textColor = .white
    subCategoryLabel.textAlignment = .left


    let horizontalFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    horizontalFlowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    self.subCategorySessionCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero , collectionViewLayout: horizontalFlowLayout)
    self.subCategorySessionCollectionView.delegate = self
    self.subCategorySessionCollectionView.dataSource = self
     self.subCategorySessionCollectionView.backgroundColor = .init(displayP3Red: 72, green: 54, blue: 13, alpha: 0.1)
    self.subCategorySessionCollectionView.register(SubCategorySessionCell.self,forCellWithReuseIdentifier: AppConstants.CellIdentifier.SubCategorySessionCellId)
    self.subCategorySessionCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false


}

override func SetViewConstraints() {

    self.contentView.addSubview(subCategoryLabel)
    subCategoryLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.width.equalToSuperview()
        make.height.equalTo(40)
        make.leftMargin.equalTo(10)
        make.top.equalTo(self.contentView.snp.top)
    }

    self.contentView.addSubview(subCategorySessionCollectionView)
    subCategorySessionCollectionView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.width.equalToSuperview()
        make.height.equalTo(160)
        make.leftMargin.equalTo(10)
        make.top.equalTo(self.subCategoryLabel.snp.bottom)
    }


}
}

 extension SelectedCategoryCell  : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell : SubCategorySessionCell = subCategorySessionCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: AppConstants.CellIdentifier.SubCategorySessionCellId, for: indexPath) as! SubCategorySessionCell

    cell.backgroundColor = .white


    cell.contentView.sizeToFit()
    cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = [UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleHeight]
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    // let width = (contentView.frame.size.width)
    return CGSize(width: 160, height: 160)
}
}
```

**Issue Here in this cell Class**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Kingfisher
import SDWebImage

class  SubCategorySessionCell: BaseUICollectionViewCell {

var backgroundImageView = UILabel()
  var imageURL : String = ""

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()


}

override func SetupUI() {




    self.backgroundImageView.backgroundColor = .black


}

override func SetViewConstraints() {

    self.contentView.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
    backgroundImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.width.equalToSuperview()
        make.height.equalTo(40)
        make.leftMargin.equalTo(10)
        make.top.equalTo(self.contentView.snp.top)
    }

}


}
```

Comment: ```My Issue is that when I try to add Any UI elements in Horizontal Collection View Cell then I could not be able to navigate from the first controller itself.``` - I don't understand your problem. When do you try to add UI elements? Navigate from first view controller where? Into the second view controller? the ```didSelectItemAt``` method isn't fired or what?

Comment: Okay, so I am adding constraints in layoutSubViews method, and found that Whenever I add a constraint in layoutSubViews method, It starts an infinite loop which is causing this issue, I can't use awakefromNib as I am setting the constraint manually and not using using any storyboard for my entire project. Which method only call once at the time of loading collectionView Cell?

Comment: Try ```didLayoutSubviews```.

Comment: Collectionviewcell don't have didLayoutSubviews.